# NLTK Naive Bayes Classifier find prior probabilities

Tags: python, nltk

I trained a Naive Bayes classifier using NLTK.

Is there any way to find what prior probability it is using for each label (I am only using 2 labels).  I used an equal number of the positive and negative tweets, so the prior should be 0.5 for each label, however whenever I classify a text with no features I always get a prob(positive)=0.8076410666128 and prob(negative)=0.192358933872.

This is regardless of the text.  I am confused as to why the model would give those probabilities for a line with 0 features and am thinking it has something to do with the prior probability of each label.

Comment: It would help if you can provide a small reproducible example of your code

Comment: Naive Bayes computes the prior probabilities according to the frequency of features during the training phase. You can have a look at the [source code here](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html#NaiveBayesClassifier) Without your source code it's hard to tell what's the problem in your case.